# member property "KEY ID" in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've got a cube, I can fetch all other member properties using `CurrentMember.PROPERTIES("property name")`

But the property that's named "KEY ID" simply returns that member's key value.

This query gets me KEY of the property:

```
WITH
MEMBER [x] AS
 [Product].[UPC].CurrentMember.PROPERTIES("KEY ID")
select
 [x] on COLUMNS, 
 [Product].[UPC].[UPC] on ROWS
FROM [my_cube]
```

If pull out KEY ID as a dimension, it gives me KEY ID's correct value.
Like this:

```
select
 [measures].[sales units] on COLUMNS, 
 [Product].[KEY ID].[KEY ID] on ROWS
FROM [my_cube]
```

What's more, I was making random changes to my query and found that the gibbery of `[Product].[UPC].CurrentMember.PROPERTIES("KEY asdf")` gives me value of KEY as well.

I searched MSDN and did a bit googling, but cannot find any documentation saying that "KEY ID" (or "KEY XXXXX") is reserved, or "KEY ID" is interpreted as "KEY". Does anyone know of any explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Here is MSDN documentation concerning properties:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144821.aspx

Another way to get the `Key` as an integer is:

```
WITH
MEMBER [x] AS
 [Product].[UPC].CurrentMember.Properties('key0', TYPED)
select
 [x] on COLUMNS, 
 [Product].[UPC].[UPC] on ROWS
FROM [my_cube]
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to help with a specific answer to your question but maybe the above helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does not answer my question though. :) I'll keep googling and looking around msdn.